# No item in ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, android-layout

Hy! I load data from my Db and I will show it in a `ListView`. Tha problem is that no item is shown. The `Listcount` is 1. The list gets the data from the db. No error occures. I have no idea why.

**Code:**

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    private ListView lv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        lv = ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.list));
        Log.e("XXX List View",lv.toString());
        onCreateDBAndDBTabled();            
    }

    private void onCreateDBAndDBTabled() {
        myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase(MY_DB_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + MY_DB_TABLE
                + " (_id integer primary key autoincrement, name varchar(100), rate integer(1), eattime datetime)"
                +";");

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor cursor = this.myDB.query(MY_DB_TABLE, new String[] { "name" }, null, null, null, null, null, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Log.e("XXX", "Courser Enter: " + cursor.getString(0));
                list.add(cursor.getString(0)); 
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }

        Log.e("XXX", "Coung:" + list.size());

        ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Main.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        lv.setAdapter(aa);
    }
}
```

**Log:**

```
09-23 08:49:30.030: ERROR/XXX(6673): Start
09-23 08:49:30.030: ERROR/XXX List View(6673): android.widget.ListView@43d13918
09-23 08:49:30.080: ERROR/XXX(6673): Courser Enter: EditText
09-23 08:49:30.090: ERROR/XXX(6673): Coung:1
```

Please help

Comment: For working with the SQLite you should use an [`SQLiteOpenHelper`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check your list object is null or not ......... then

http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/using-arrayadapter-and-listview-in-android-applications

http://www.dotnetexpertsforum.com/populate-listview-using-arrayadapter-in-android-t1437.html

https://github.com/sudar/android-samples

also check **List list = new ArrayList();**  size there are list is empty or not if empty try to get element.............

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted shows that you are creating an empty table, which means that the cursor will not contain any value. First insert something into the DB, then read it.